# Converting private ip to public ip

Tags: ipv4, ip

how can I find the public IP address of a private IP address if i don't have access to the device?

Comment: If you don't have access to the device, the network isn't under your control, so the question is off-topic here. Please read the [help/on-topic] for what is on/off-topic.

Comment: That is my device and I even have the password!

Comment: Then you have the public IP address for it. I'm not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

I used a friend's suggestion and checked at my Facebook (or as he said Google too) security options and by hovering on the location, IP was shown.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Protocols above OSI layer-4, servers, and applications are all off-topic here.

Comment: I think this is helpful for the community!

Comment: It is off-topic here. This is good for the [su] community. Anyone who controls the network already has this information.